# Not able to compile LibXML in 64 bit HPUX

Tags: perl, 64-bit, hp-ux

We were trying to compile the LibXML module for perl in 64 bit HPUX machine.

We ran the .configure like below:

```
./configure --prefix=/software/opt/HPUX11/ia64/libxml2-2.7.7 --target=ia64-hpux
```

The compiler is set to 64 bit: `export CC="cc +DD64"`

Then we ran `gmake install`, the following error occured:

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/software/src/libxml2-2.7.7'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link cc +DD64     -o xmllint xmllint.o ./libxml2.la -lpthread   -lm
libtool: link: cc +DD64 -o .libs/xmllint xmllint.o  ./.libs/libxml2.so -lpthread -lm -Wl,+b -Wl,/software/opt/HPUX11/ia64/libxml2-2.7.7/lib
ld: Unknown input file type: "./.libs/libxml2.so"
Fatal error.
gmake[1]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/software/src/libxml2-2.7.7'
gmake: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Could somebody tell us how to fix this?